# Is escape velocity really a velocity (rather than a speed)?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, velocity, speed, escape-velocity

The term [escape velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) is quite common to us. But we know velocity is a dimension dependent on the direction. But the escape velocity has same value irrespective of from where it is thrown from the earth. So its just the magnitude that matters, not the direction. In that  sense it should be given the name as escape speed. But it is not given so, can anyone explain?

Comment: wiki :The term escape velocity is actually a misnomer, and it is often more accurately referred to as escape speed since the necessary speed is a scalar quantity which is independent of direction (assuming a non-rotating planet and ignoring atmospheric friction or relativistic effects).

Comment: There are a lot of technical misnomers in science. As long as you know what is meant that's fine. Having said that, "escape speed" just sounds horrible and reminds me far more of a high speed police chase than physics.

Comment: @CuriousOne: My physics book called it the escape speed, not escape velocity (though may have mentioned the latter term as a common misnomer). So it can be called as such, and I think that make more sense.

Comment: @mike4ty4: I take no offense with it being used. :-)

Comment: Would the term “exorbiting speed” be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, escape velocity is a speed, not a velocity. As to why, see the [etymology of the word velocity](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=velocity):

*early 15c., from Latin velocitatem (nominative velocitas) "swiftness, speed," from velox (genitive velocis) "swift, speedy, rapid, quick," of uncertain origin*.

Velocity used to mean speed, and we still say things like "high velocity bullet". The vector-quantity meaning came later. Interestingly, when you look at translations of Einstein's papers such as [here](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol4-trans/205?highlightText=%22velocity%20of%20light%22), you see the word velocity used instead of the word speed. Then when you backtrack to the original German, you find the original word was [Geschwindigkeit](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/~searchResults?searchMode=quick&searchStartIdx=1&searchEndIdx=20&searchResultsStep=20&searchMetaType=Book&context=-2&searchText=geschwindigkeit). Native German speakers have advised me that it means [both speed and velocity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Geschwindigkeit).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *escape velocity* should really be *escape speed*. The [Wikipedia article on escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) states this explicitly.

I doubt there is any logical reason for using the term *escape velocity* and I suspect it is an accident of history. You might want to ask on the [History of Science SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) how the term originated - a quick Google failed to retrieve any information about the origin of the phrase.