# Escape velocity given at an angle

Tags: escape-velocity

We know that the escape velocity of Earth is about 11.2Km/s but what if we give that same velocity to an object at any angle let's just take 30° will it still escape from Earth's gravitational field or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is escape velocity really a velocity (rather than a speed)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193497/is-escape-velocity-really-a-velocity-rather-than-a-speed), [Escape velocity at an angle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263561).

Answer (score 4):

Escape velocity is not dependent on direction. It was initially calculated using conservation of energy (setting kinetic energy equal to potential energy).

Since energy is a scalar quantity, the angle $\theta$ that an object is launched at will not change the escape velocity.

So $v_{escape} = 11.2 $ km/s