# What is angle of escape velocity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, escape-velocity

We know if a object has escape velocity (EV) it reaches space (ignore atmosphere friction), but at what angle. if an object travels parallel to earth surface with EV, will it escape curvature and reach space. If it travel horizontal and  after reaching EV, it make slighlty an angle, will it reach space

```
          Thank you for you answers. But my main question is if body travels horizondaly(parallel to earth surface), reaching escape velocity, and  ***without making an angle*** will it escape to earth orbit
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is escape velocity really a velocity (rather than a speed)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193497/)

Comment: _[Escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity)_ isn't about "reaching space." It is a critical speed whose value depends on the location of some ballistic projectile relative to a massive gravitating body. If there's no air resistance, then a projectile moving with less than escape velocity must either _orbit_ the larger body forever, or else it will crash into the larger body.  If the projectile is moving with greater than escape velocity, and if it is not on a collision course, then its distance from the larger body will continue to increase forever.

Comment: P.S., Re "Reaching Space..." Space is defined by some people as everything above the [Kármán line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line). That is supposedly the altitude above which it is theoretically impossible for an aircraft to fly. The actual value is somewhat arbitrary since it depends on what exactly the words "aircraft" and "fly" mean.